# How do I group this data into an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, group-by

My table looks like this:

```
artist_id | song_id | user_id
a1          s1        u1
a1          s2        u1
a2          s9        u1
a3          s15       u2
```

I'd like my output to look something like:

```
Array
    (
    [u1] => Array
        (
         [a1] => Array
           (
               [0] => s1
               [1] => s2
           )
         [a2] => Array
           (
               [0] => s9
           )
   )
   [u2] => Array
        (
         [a3] => Array
           (
               [0] => s15
           )

   )
```

)

**Where should I start?**

I'm not sure my approach is most efficient:

- Grab and group `user_id`, loop thru them.
- For each `user_id`, grab the `artist_id`.
- For each `artist_id` grab the `song_id`s underneath.

Is there a way to make this one query?

Comment: How is your DB set up? Do you have a User table with foreign keys to the song or artist tables? Do you have a mapping table?

Comment: Yes, so each column has it's own table.  Essentially I am trying to grab user and what artist they are attached to and then list all songs under that artist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the following results set from MySQL query. Use any one of the library PDO or MySQLi.

```
<?php
$results = array(
                0 => array('artist_id' => 'a1', 'song_id' => 's1', 'user_id' => 'u1'),
                1 => array('artist_id' => 'a1', 'song_id' => 's2', 'user_id' => 'u1'),
                2 => array('artist_id' => 'a2', 'song_id' => 's9', 'user_id' => 'u1'),
                3 => array('artist_id' => 'a3', 'song_id' => 's15', 'user_id' => 'u2')
            );
echo '<pre>';print_r($results);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Try with this,

```
<?php
$new_array = array();

foreach($results as $keys=>$values) {
    $new_array[$values['user_id']][$values['artist_id']][] = $values['song_id'];
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($new_array);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Note:
You can't get it from single query, it is depends on the results set. i explained with your result set,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As long as I see, you need ALL results in your table, no `count`, no `sum`, etc.

So there's nothing you can `group by` in SQL query, just select them all out and group them in PHP:

```
$result=array();
$mysqli_result=$mysqli->query("SELECT `artist_id`,`song_id`,`user_id` FROM `songs`");
while($row=$mysqli_result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if(empty($result[$row["user_id"]]))
        $result[$row["user_id"]]=array();
    if(empty($result[$row["user_id"]][$row["artist_id"]]))
        $result[$row["user_id"]][$row["artist_id"]]=array();
    $result[$row["user_id"]][$row["artist_id"]][]=$row["song_id"];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: It is not necessary to declare parent levels before pushing data as a subarray.